# Create function for CamanJS Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins, camanjs

is there any chance to create a function that i can call?

if i'm putting the following lines in the document ready function it works:

```
Caman("25-02-2014_16-37-13.jpg", "#example-canvas", function () {
  this.brightness(brightness);
  this.render(function () {
    check = this.toBase64(); 
  });
```

But if i'm doing this i can't call. So I tried this:

```
function icancall()
{
  Caman("25-02-2014_16-37-13.jpg", "#example-canvas", function () {
  this.brightness(brightness);
  this.render(function () {
    check = this.toBase64();
  });
}
```

So i thought i can call this with icancall(); But nothing happened. What am I doing wrong?
What i want do: executing the Caman function on a button click.

I hope you can help me !

Comment: Putting it inside a function should not affect the Caman code.  Did you verify that you're getting to your function icancall

also your tab spacing on your function is wrong.  You need to indent below Caman.

Answer (score 0):

```
            function resz(){

        Caman("25-02-2014_16-37-13.jpg", "#example-canvas", function  () {
            try {


                this.render(function () {
                    var image = this.toBase64();

                    xyz(image); // call that function where you pass filters 

                });
            } catch (e) { alert(e) }
        });
```

}

[Apply CamanJS filters by this function]

```
 function xyz(image){

                var filters_k = $('#filters');

                filters_k.click(function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var f = $(this);

                    if (f.is('.active')) {
                        // Apply filters only once
                        return false;
                    }

                    filters_k.removeClass('active');
                    f.addClass('active');
                    var effect = $.trim(f[0].id);
                    Caman(canvasID, img, function () {

                        if (effect in this) {

                            this.revert(false);
                            this[effect]();
                            this.render();

                        }

                    });
                });  
            }
```